# display a complete node

Tags: 6

i want to display a node (from a menu callback), but when i do this:

```
echo node_view(node_load($_POST['classid']));
```

it displays the node without the page template. How do show the entire node, just like someone navigated to '/node/xxx'.

by the way, i can't just redirect to 'node/xxxx' because i need to leave the url without any parameter (stupid requirement by employers)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange that node_view is not returning a fully formatted node. The node module calls `node_view` inside it's own `hook_menu` to handle `node/%nid` requests.

Is there any chance that your CSS is selecting on something specific to `node/%nid` pages or your templates are setup in a non-standard way.

Can you show us the exact HTML string that is being returned by that function and the HTML string you are expecting?

Comment: the html returned is exactly what is generated by node.tpl.php. the node is a content type, that has page-content_type.tpk.php template. this template doesn't show on node_view above (but does show on node/xxxx)

Answer (score 0):

Only a year late.

```
$url = url('node/XXX', array('absolute' => TRUE));
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

That will do the trick under most circumstances.